# how to put a text in donut chart provided by google using simple html, javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any attribute in google chart?
I am new to google charts. Please help!
I have the following code:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

var options = {
   title: 'My Daily Activities',
   pieHole: 0.4,
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no such attribute for donut charts. So, just try a div using z-index such that it would be displayed over the chart.